# Task doesn't run in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have a task, but processes inside it don't run in parallel. Second one waits for the first one to compelete. Can you explain why and how can I correct this? I want both of them run at the same time.

And second question, Should I use task instead of threads?

Thanks in advance.

```
 new Task(() =>
            {
                Counter1();
                Counter2();
            }).Start();




    private void Counter2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            label2.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Counter1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            label3.Text = i.ToString();
            if(i == 15)
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tasks run regular methods.  You want two tasks.

Comment: I wait something like that: Parallel.Invoke. Can't do it?

Comment: Yes; that would also work.

Comment: Can you please show me if I want to make it with Task how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460705%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and call `Counter1()` and `Counter2()` as shown in following example from MSDN (after updating the `()` anonymous lambda invocation to invoke your 2 methods.

```
        #region ParallelTasks
        // Perform three tasks in parallel on the source array
        Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");
                             GetLongestWord(words);
                         },  // close first Action

                         () =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                             GetMostCommonWords(words);
                         }, //close second Action

                         () =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("Begin third task...");
                             GetCountForWord(words, "species");
                         } //close third Action
                     ); //close parallel.invoke

        Console.WriteLine("Returned from Parallel.Invoke");
        #endregion
```

Comment: I know, I can do it in this way but I want to achieve this with Task. Is there a way?

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only way. From the same MSDN article, see `The Parallel.Invoke method provides a convenient way to run any number of arbitrary statements concurrently. Just pass in an Action delegate for each item of work. The easiest way to create these delegates is to use lambda expressions. The lambda expression can either call a named method or provide the code inline. The following example shows a basic Invoke call that creates and starts two tasks that run concurrently.`